# SQL unexpected result when mixing numbers and strings

Tags: mysql, string, integer

I have no idea why this happens. Sql statement below returns 'test2'. Why does it do that? It seems like it only captures the first number of the string I gave. I expected an empty result.

Query:

```
SELECT article FROM news WHERE id = '2aas13'
```

Table 'news':

```
id | article
------------
1  | test
2  | test2
3  | test3
```

Database used: mysql

Comment: That's exactly what it does.See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html

Comment: Thanks, type conversion was what I was looking for.